# ¿Cómo usar la función round dentro de un printf en C++?

Tags: c++

¿Cómo usar el `round` dentro del `printf`? Necesito que aproxime el valor de los números indicados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
// Ejercicio  3
    float numero_1=-85.235680;
    float numero_2=3.00000;
    printf("Numero flotante a: %f   Numero entero b: %f:", numero_1 ,round(3), numero_2 ,round(3));}
```

Comment: Prueba con mi solución

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
// Ejercicio  3
    float numero_1=-85.235680;
    float numero_2=3.00000;
    printf("Numero flotante : %f   Numero entero: %.0f\n"
           "Numero flotante : %f   Numero entero: %.0f\n",
            numero_1 ,round(numero_1), numero_2, round(numero_2));
    return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
Numero flotante : -85.235680   Numero entero: -85
Numero flotante : 3.000000   Numero entero: 3
```